# A problem on limits of functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Find two functions $ f(x) $ and $ g(x)$ such that

1) $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=10$; $\quad\lim_{x\to 10} f(x)=100$ but  $\lim_{x\to 0} f(g(x))$ doesn't exist.

2)  $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=10$; $\quad\lim_{x\to 10} f(x)=100$ but  $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(g(x))=10 $ and  $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(g(x))=100 $

3) $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=10$; $\quad\lim_{x\to 10} f(x)=100$ but  $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(g(x))=10 $ and  $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(g(x)) $ doesn't exist

I could only do the 1st one and found the other 2 difficult hence any help would be appreciated.

My solution to the 1st one was

$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+10,  & \text{if $x<0$ } \\
10, & \text{if $x\ge 0$ }  \\
\end{cases} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
100,  & \text{if $x<10$ or x>10} \\
50, & \text{if $x= 10$ }  \\
\end{cases}
$$

Then:
$$f(g(x)) =
\begin{cases}
100,  & \text{if $x<0$ } \\
50, & \text{if $x\ge 0$ }  \\
\end{cases}$$
 Is it correct? and please help on other 2

Comment: For the first one you have given a valid example.

Comment: Example for 2nd, just modify your example by defining $f(10)=10$, instead of $50$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for 1st: Yours

Example for 2nd: Just modify your example by defining $f$ to be 10 when $x$ is 10, instead of 50.

Example for 3rd: Let
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}10+x\cos\frac1x&x<0\\10&x\ge0\end{cases}$$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}10&x=10\\100&x\ne10\end{cases}$$

See that $g$ does have limit of $10$ at $0$ (for $x\cos\frac1x$ is continuous at $0$) and that $g$ keeps going above and below 10 as $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$.

$g\left(-\frac1{2n\pi}\right)<10$ so $f\circ g$ there is $100$.

$g\left(-\frac2{(2n+1)\pi}\right)=10$ so $f\circ g$ there is $10$.

Enlarging $n$ in each case you keep approaching zero. We clearly see that the left hand limit does not exist.
The right hand limit however clearly exists.

Answer (score 1):

For the second problem note that your first example has $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(g(x))=50$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(g(x))=100$, so a minor adjustment helps.

For the third one, try something like
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}10&\text{if }x=10,\\100&\text{if }x\ne10\end{cases}$$
$$ g(x)=\begin{cases}10&\text{if }x\ge0,\\10+x\sin \frac1x&\text{if }x<0.\end{cases}$$
Then $f(g(x))=10$ for $x>0$ whereas for $x<0$, we $f(g(x))=100$ if $x=-\frac1{n\pi}$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ and $f(g(x))=10$ otherwise.